# Объединить элементы массива

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти все повторяющиеся `products.id` и объединить `quantity`.
Должно получиться вот так:

```
products = [{id: 5, quantity: 25}, {id: 3, quantity: 15}, {id: 4, quantity: 164}]
```

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    products: [{
      id: 5,
      quantity: 5
    }, {
      id: 3,
      quantity: 2
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    products: [{
      id: 4,
      quantity: 75
    }, {
      id: 5,
      quantity: 20
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    products: [{
      id: 3,
      quantity: 13
    }, {
      id: 4,
      quantity: 89
    }]
  },
]

let allProducts = [];
let products = [];

function getAllProducts() {
  arr.forEach(value => {
    value.products.forEach(product => allProducts.push(product))
  })
  concatProducts(allProducts)
}

function concatProducts(arr) {
  arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.id === b.id ? products.push({
      id: a.id,
      quantity: a.quantity + b.quantity
    }) : products.push(b);
  });
  console.log(products)
}

getAllProducts()
```

Comment: 13 -> 15, 154 -> 164 ??

Comment: @Igor все верно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    products: [
      {id: 5, quantity: 5},
      {id: 3, quantity: 2}
    ]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    products: [
      {id: 4, quantity: 75},
      {id: 5, quantity: 20}
    ]
  }, {
    id: 3,
    products: [
      {id: 3, quantity: 13},
      {id: 4, quantity: 89}
    ]
  }
];

function getAllProducts(arr) {
  const allProducts = {};
  arr.forEach(value => {
    value.products.forEach(prod => {
      if (allProducts[prod.id] === undefined)
        allProducts[prod.id] = prod.quantity;
      else
        allProducts[prod.id] += prod.quantity;
    });
  })
  const products = [];
  for (let id in allProducts) {
    products.push({id: id, quantity: allProducts[id]});
  }
  return products;
}

console.log(getAllProducts(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    products: [
      { id: 5, quantity: 5 }, 
      { id: 3, quantity: 2 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    products: [
      { id: 4, quantity: 75 },
      { id: 5, quantity: 20 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    products: [
      { id: 3, quantity: 13 }, 
      { id: 4, quantity: 89 }
    ]
  },
]

var res = arr.reduce((res, item) => {
  item.products.reduce((res, item) => {
    if (!res[item.id])
      res[item.id] = 0;
    res[item.id] += item.quantity;
    return res;
  }, res);
  return res;
}, {});

var result = [];
for (var key in res)
  result.push({ id: +key, quantity: res[key]});
  
console.log(result);
```